# findFirstBy and findTopBy does not work with Spring Data Elasticsearch

Tags: spring-data-elasticsearch

I am trying to get latest record within collection using findFirstBy and findTopBy, but its not working with Spring Data Elasticsearch and throwing NullPointerException.

My repository method is as follows -

```
@Repository
public interface MyRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<PointInTime, String> {
     PointInTime findFirstByDbInstanceIdOrderByCreationTimeDesc(String dbInstanceId);
}
```

Exception is -

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchTemplate.queryForPage(ElasticsearchTemplate.java:289)
        at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchTemplate.queryForObject(ElasticsearchTemplate.java:233)
        at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.query.ElasticsearchPartQuery.execute(ElasticsearchPartQuery.java:59)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:421)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:381)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:512)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy66.findFirstByOrderByCreationTimeDesc(Unknown Source)
        at com.comp.prod.assetmanagement.service.PointInTimeService.getLatestPointInTime(PointInTimeService.java:103)
        at com.comp.prod.assetmanagement.controller.PointInTimeController.getPointInTimes(PointInTimeController.java:135)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:781)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:721)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:301)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at com.comp.prod.common.filter.CloudCORSFilter.doFilter(CloudCORSFilter.java:79)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:186)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.web.Log4jServletFilter.doFilter(Log4jServletFilter.java:66)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:136)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:74)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:516)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1015)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:652)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1575)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1533)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Doesn't look like this will be supported until version 4.0 of Spring Data Elasticsearch: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/pull/305

Answer (score 4):

It's an old topic but I have the same problem right now.

It seems that the First and Top keyword are not implemented, at least in the current version of Elasticsearch Spring Data (1.2.2.RELEASE).

The best alternative is to use a Pageable and pass `new PageItem(0, 1)` as parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can also give this solution a try,

```
PointInTime pointInTime = null;

if (myRepository.findAllByDbInstanceIdOrderByCreationTimeDesc(dbInstanceId) != null 
    && !myRepository.findAllByDbInstanceIdOrderByCreationTimeDesc(dbInstanceId).isEmpty()) {
   
pointInTime = myRepository.findAllByDbInstanceIdOrderByCreationTimeDesc(dbInstanceId).get(0);

}
```

Assume that myRepository is the autowired object of your MyRepository Interface.

Comment: Your answer is not good. findAll() will never return null, it will return empty list if no elements found. No need to call the method twice. Call if for once and save the returned data then check the condition. The right way to use pageable and avoid to repeat calling same method. Also try to avoid using findAll without pagination it will give you bad performance for big datasets.

Comment: Thanks @MohdAlomar for improving my answer. Heads up.

Answer (score -2):

In Spring data we can retrieve top record, let's try this method

```
findTop1ByOrderByClientRoleIdAsc()
```

**ClientRoleId** is a column name